# setting value of a label depending on checkbox JQuery

Tags: jquery, attr

i'm just trying to set a labels value depending on the change() event of a checkbox.  my checkbox and label code is;

```
<div class="Sell" style="width: 47px;"><input type="checkbox" id="chkSell" class="_1"/></div>
<div class="BuySelllbl" style="width: 10px;"><label id="lblBuySell_1"></label></div>
```

and the JQuery is as follows;

```
    $("#chkSell").live('change',function(){
    var y = $(this).attr("class");
    var x = "#lblBuySell" + y;  
    alert(x);
    if(this.checked){       
        $(x).attr("value","S");
        $(x).attr("style","color: red;");
    }else{
        $(x).removeAttr("value");
    }
});
```

the alert outputs the correct id of the label everytime, but nothing gets set in the .attr properties.  Is there something incorrect about my syntax? Any help is great.
Thank you,
NickG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property value doesn't have any value for label, you should replace your statement for:

```
$("#chkSell").live('change',function(){
    var y = $(this).attr("class");
    var x = "#lblBuySell" + y;  
    alert(x);
    if(this.checked){       
        $(x).html("S");
        $(x).attr("style","color: red;");
    }else{
        $(x).removeAttr("value");
    }
```

Comment: thank you @Markus i really appreciate it, i didn't know that value wouldn't be accepted, inline isn't the property value?

Comment: The property value will only work with input types.
Label it's an structure, so you're adding something inside of it, that's why u have to use html method.
Just for a tip, you can use the css method as mentioned on other answers. $(x).html('S').css('color', 'red');

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the way you verify that the checkbox is checked.

```
// First method - Recommended
$('#checkbox').prop('checked')  // Boolean true

// Second method - Makes code more readable (e.g. in if statements)
$('#checkbox').is(':checked')  // Boolean true

// Third method - Selecting the checkbox & filtering by :checked selector
$('#checkbox:checked').length  // Integer >0
$('#checkbox:checked').size()  // .size() can be used instead of .length

// Fourth method - Getting DOM object reference
$('#checkbox').get(0).checked  // Boolean true
$('#checkbox')[0].checked      // Boolean true (same as above)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#chkSell").live('change',function(){
    var x = $("#lblBuySell." + $(this).attr("class"));  

    if(this.checked == true)
    {
        x.attr("value","S");
        x.attr("style","color: red;");
    }
    else
        x.removeAttr("value");
});
```

You can check if you have selected no elements by using the length variable

```
x.length
```